# Rails, path_names and nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

My routes:

```
resources :events, :path_names => { :new => "organize" } do
    resources :forums
end
```

With these routes, I'll get urls like `/events/:event_id/forums/organize`. I don't want the path_names to propagate to my nested routes... Do I have to redefine `path_names` for them? Or use `scope`?

```
resources :events, :path_names => { :new => "organize" } do
    scope :path_names => { :new => "new" } do
        resources :forums
        # other nested resources...
    end
end
```

Or (my favorite, until you find a better solution ;))

```
resources :events, :path_names => { :new => "organize" }
resources :events, :only => [] do
    #nested resources...
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? if you don't think so, you can also tell me which one is the best in your opinion.

Comment: What about defining `:path_names` for forums in the same way?

Comment: That's an option, but not the best one I think. Because I have a lot of nested resources, not just forums. So worst case scenario, I would use the 2 other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the last option:

```
resources :events, :path_names => { :new => "organize" }
resources :events, :only => [] do
    #nested resources...
end
```